# Mysql configuration errror : using password (NO) instead of YES

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I try to connect mysql via PHPMYADMIN, using my password, but it can't stop telling me that (access denied, using password NO) but i'm using a password :O

When i connect via the console with my password, **it works but not on phpmyadmin**.

It's really weird.

Do you have an idea to fix that ?

edit: it worked couple of days ago, because i created 2 databases and 2 users via phpmyadmin...

Thanks

edit : **When i'm using CHROME it's working unless FireFox ...**
any ideas ?

Comment: I think you need to show your phpMyAdmin configuration.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Does the problem persist if you use another browser?

Comment: @quassnoi thank you, you find out the problem : using  google chrome : WORKS / using FF : don't work.

How to fix ?

Comment: I think you need to show your phpMyAdmin configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar issue on mediatemple once. It's related to the cookies and/or sessions in your browser getting messed up. Try clearing your cookies.

Answer (score 0):

if you use WAMPP after updating user "root", you also have to reconfigure in the `"C: \ WAMPP \ apps \ phpmyadmin \ config.inc.php`

On line

`$ cfg ['Servers'] [$ i] ['auth_type'] = 'config';`

you change `"config"` with `"cookies"` and then restart WAMPP .. good luck